# Python Keras LSTM Features order relevance

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, predict

I want to know if the order of features on array interferes on training model and validation scores.
For exemple if I had this list of features to train my model:

["close", "close_returns", "log_returns", "open", "open_returns", "open_log_returns"]

If I invert de order like:

["close", "open","log_returns", "close_returns", "open_log_returns", "open_returns"]

This make any difference on predicted model? Or the sort order dosent interfere?
If the order interfere. How I can know what the beast order?

And how I can know if determinate feature is relevant or not for my lstm model on Keras?

Comment: LSTM is used for sequential data. If your input is not sequential i.e changing the order of inputs does not distort the data, you probably should consider Conv1D or something else other than LSTM.

Comment: And how I can determine if some feature is relevant or not in my LSTM model

Comment: I don't think there is any hard and fast rule other than using your background knowledge about data. You should try to train the model with prospective inputs and then try changing them to see which results in best performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To determine feature relevance, there are several methods out there such as ALE, Anchors, LIME, and SHAP. From these, I recommend SHAP as it offers pretty nice and informative visualizations such as the force, dependence, and feature importance plots. Here is a link to a Python notebook using [Keras LSTM for IMDB Sentiment Classification](https://github.com/slundberg/shap/blob/master/notebooks/deep_explainer/Keras%20LSTM%20for%20IMDB%20Sentiment%20Classification.ipynb) where the force plot is generated for that specific problem. Nevertheless, SHAP can also be applied to regression problems. Here is another [link](https://shap.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#plots) to SHAP's API where you could find how to get the other plots. Have in mind that some visualizations are generated for specific samples like the force plot and others for the whole set (feature importance).

Information about how SHAP works as well as its advantages and disadvantages can be found [here](https://christophm.github.io/interpretable-ml-book/shap.html).

Answer (score 0):

The order of the features does not make much of a difference as you will have a separate output node for each feature.

What matters is the order of the events (the rows). This is the sequence you will be modelling and predicting with the model. To determine which features to use you must know what you are modelling. Putting all of them in will give you predictions for all the columns but will also probably make the model harder to train and optimize.

So you should think about which of the features you actually need to include in the model. For example, can you infer feature A from feature B? If so, feature A does not need to be included as its easy to calculate.

What about features that do not add much information such as columns that do not change very often. Are they necessary?